# Yii2 RBAC check permissions without each actions in controller

Tags: php, oop, yii2

How i can  check permissions in one place?
I don't want to check each function individually.

My RBAC controller. 
I would like check permission for logged in user for all actions in the controller.  Now I have to  use `Yii::$app->user->can('...')` individually for each actions in the controller

```
$admin = $auth->createRole('Admin');
$moderator = $auth->createRole('Moderator');

$createPost=$auth->createPermission('createPost');
$updatePost=$auth->createPermission('updatePost');
$deletePost=$auth->createPermission('deletePost');
$createCategory=$auth->createPermission('createCategory');
$updateCategory=$auth->createPermission('updateCategory');
$deleteCategory=$auth->createPermission('deleteCategory');


$auth->add($admin);
$auth->add($moderator);
$auth->add($createPost);
$auth->add($updatePost);
$auth->add($deletePost);
$auth->add($createCategory);
$auth->add($updateCategory);
$auth->add($deleteCategory);
```

Here I assign role with permissions,  but i  never use these permissions because write manually  in behavior->(like  your example)

What is goal, create permissons in RBAC, if  this not working?   If  I would like  add    premium user.  I  could   only add action in controller e.g. actionPremium and set in behavior actions for premium user.

e.g

action=>['premium']
roles=>['premiumUser']

and one more question. 
How in behavior customize  message  error?

```
$auth->addChild($admin,$moderator);
$auth->addChild($admin,$createCategory);
$auth->addChild($admin,$updateCategory);
$auth->addChild($admin,$deleteCategory);
$auth->addChild($moderator, $createPost);
$auth->addChild($moderator, $updatePost);
$auth->addChild($moderator, $deletePost);


$auth->assign($admin,1);
$auth->assign($moderator,2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the permission allowed in controller  for all action in behaviors

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index','view'], // these action are accessible 
                                                   //only the yourRole1 and yourRole2
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['yourRole1', 'yourRole2'],
                ],
                [    // all the action are accessible to superadmin, admin and manager
                    'allow' => true,  
                    'roles' => ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'manager'],
                ],   
            ],
        ],        
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

The role you assigned in behaviors are for action .. allowd or deny .. the if a role had an allowed action in behaviors then he can execute otherwise he get permission denied 403 .. (not authorized) ..

You can also check the role in procedural code with

```
if ( Yii::$app->User->can('admin') ){
    .....
    yourdCode
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, but tell me, what for  create permissions in RBAC like as my example. createPost,updatePost etc, and then  associate her with  roles in table auth_item_child?
If i can  manually  write need actions ?  can you explain me this?

Comment: @Demolog  please explain your goal in more detailed way , I don't understand well (eventually edit you question  .. )

Comment: I have update the answer hoping this is what you are looking for  .. for the  behavior customize message error i suggest you of posting a more appropriate question ..

Comment: Ok i used   denyCallback ;)